# Regex replace all non-numeric characters except for certain character patterns

Tags: c#, regex

I am having a hard time trying to figure out this regex pattern.  I want to replace all non-numeric characters in a string except for certain alpha character patterns.

For example i am trying:

```
string str = "The sky is blue 323.05 lnp days of the year";

str = Regex.Replace(str, "(^blue|lnp|days)[^.0-9]", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I would like it to return:

"blue 323.05 lnp days"

but I can't figure out how to get it to match the entire character pattern in the expression.

Comment: You can try [`\b((?!blue|lnp|days)[^.0-9 ]+?)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/RQRTab/1/)

Comment: Thank you!  That does seem to work if use the @ symbol in front of the expression.  What if someone mistypes the numerical value.


string str = "The sky is blue 32nn3.05 lnp days of the year";

Comment: Maybe `(\b(?:blue|lnp|days)\b|\d*\.?\d+)|[^\d\s]` and replace with group 1 https://regex101.com/r/rZfCXJ/1

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest capturing what you need to keep and just matching what you need to remove:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"(\s*\b(?:blue|lnp|days)\b\s*)|[^.0-9]", "$1").Trim();
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5Cs*%5Cb%28%3F%3Ablue%7Clnp%7Cdays%29%5Cb%5Cs*%29%7C%5B%5E.0-9%5Cn%5D&i=The%20sky%20is%20blue%20323.05%20lnp%20days%20of%20the%20year%0D%0AThe%20sky%20is%20blue%2032nn3.05%20lnp%20days%20of%20the%20year&r=%241). Note that the eventual leading/trailing spaces will be trimmed with `.Trim()`.

The regex means:

- `(\s*\b(?:blue|lnp|days)\b\s*)` - Group 1 (`$1`):

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\b(?:blue|lnp|days)\b`  - one of the three words as whole words
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `|` - or
- `[^.0-9]` - any char but `.` and ASCII digit.